# Save gt() table with a specific height and width

Tags: r, gt

The latest versions of `gt()` use `webshot2` under the covers.  I’m trying to output a longer-than-wide table in a 16:9 aspect ratio by overriding the `webshot2` output sizes explicitly, but this isn’t working:

```r
mtcars[, 1:3] %>%
  head(5) %>%
  gt() %>%
  gtsave(filename = "xyz.png", vwidth = 998, vheight = 561)
```

Perhaps an alternate approach might be, how might I format my table to a 16:9 compliant size and then simply let `gtsave()` work as it always does?

Any thoughts as to how I can output the graphic to the explicit size I need?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are looking for `cols_width ()` from the `gt` package

```
mtcars[, 1:3] %>%
  head(5) %>%
  gt() %>%
  cols_width(everything() ~ px(150)) %>%
  gtsave(filename = "xyz.png")
```

[image]

Comment: I’m familiar with `cols_width()`, thanks. No, what I’m really looking for is a way to specify the final table size in pixels so that I can produce output in a 16:9 aspect ratio without necessarily re-sizing each column individually to achieve that.

Comment: On reflection, @Wael, this can be a useful approach for statically-sized tables, so long as I calculate the dimensions necessary to get a table to a 16:9-compatible size.

Comment: @redlrossi definitely yes, it forces to have large columns if there is few ones.

Answer (score 0):

In R Shiny I adjust the gt table height, width, and scrolling as shown below:
div(style='height:400px; width: 800px; overflow-y: scroll', gt_output("gt_table"))