Image quality of gtsave()
Is there a way to control the quality of the PNG file when saving a gt table using gtsave()?

Perhaps these might help? https://forum.posit.co/t/change-the-size-in-gtsave/49859/3 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75726398/save-gt-table-with-a-specific-height-and-width
